# Rails Master Key and deployment environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

On my development environment (my local Mac) and my test server (Ubuntu), I set up a couple of environment variables:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY = ....... (master key is the same for development and test)
RAILS_ENV= .... (development and test)
```

I generated the `credentials.yml.enc` file locally.

I am getting ready to push the application to a staging server, but I do not want to use the same MASTER_KEY.

I could regenerate the `credentials.yml.enc` file on the staging server, but then it would be empty and I would have to do something like:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

And then enter all the variables.

I am thinking of doing the following:

1. Locally generate 2 separate `credentials.yml.enc` files.
2. Have a script copy the proper `credentials.yml.enc` file to the server (test or staging)

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If you really want to do it, I think what you're proposing is probably your best bet. But why would you want to do that? I fail to understand what benefit you would get from messing with 2 separate `credentials` files, as you'll still need to have the server's master key stored on your local machine in order to edit the copy of the file that you intend to use for the server. If you're trying to avoid having the same key stored on both, that already defeats the purpose.

Comment: `credentials.yml.enc` is an encrypted file, which can only be decrypted with its associated master key. [It can be stored in version control, as long as the master key is kept safe](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials). When you commit changes to the file, the updated credentials can then be used by the server and your teammates (as long as they all have the same master key) and nobody has to edit their files separately. That's the whole point of it, otherwise you could just store everything in environment variables on each machine and ditch the file altogether.

Answer (score 0):

By running

```
EDITOR=VIM rails credentials:edit -e production
```

you will get a new key in `config/environments/production.key`

Each env will have its own key

**Never commit** your keys, and keep them safe